# Python runs previous code instead a current one

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Visual Code Studio or Sublime text 3 and I'm suddenly getting output of previously ran code instead of a current one. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen if you recompile the code (in VSCode or Sublime) or run it with IDLE or the command line?

Comment: Yes it happens when I run python script in command line as well. Anyway by recompiling the code do you mean run it with ctrl+F5? Because thats how I usually run my code.

Comment: strange.... try to locate any __pycache__ folders in your project, delete them. Also any *.pyc files. Python, however, should overwrite those files by itself.

Comment: @imolitor Well, I've found hundreds of pycache folders and .pyc files. Should I delete them all?

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is not normal to a Python environment. Deleting the __ pycache __ folders and *.pyc files shall only test if the code executes correctly without the Python generated cache files. The cache files are for executing code faster when it has not been changed. However, Python should generate new cache files where code has changed. So yes, delete them all and see if your code is executing correctly then.

Comment: @imolitor So I uninstalled everything regarding python and visual studio code, deleted every python file. Then installed all of it all over again and it still did it :))) The only thing that helped was deleting the python script itself. Now it runs clean without unwanted previous code.